# What explains this difference in partisanship with statewide black officials?

Tags: united-states, parties, demographics

I was looking at the partisanship of black Americans today. The first one really stood out to me. I found this bizarre. Look:

```
Position                                           % Democratic
Statewide office (after VRA, Senate or governor)     55
Two Party Vote 2016 President                        92
House member 116th Congress                          98
```

I know the sample size for the first one is small. But, it is not as small as it could be. Why the large deviation in partisanship of statewide officials?

Sources: https://www.cnn.com/election/2016/results/exit-polls, https://www.washingtonpost.com/outlook/why-the-next-black-president-could-be-a-republican/2017/08/03/42a7675a-73a7-11e7-8839-ec48ec4cae25_story.html

Comment: Politics SE has a policy of limiting actual questions in a question post to only one. So maybe ask multiple questions instead and split this one up.

Comment: I edited it to fix the problem.

Comment: At least part of the answer is likely the same as the answer to why very "blue" places like New York City [elect more Republicans as mayor than President](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50600/why-did-nyc-vote-republican-candidates-for-mayor-from-1993-2009-but-not-for-othe)

Comment: Not so much. NYC mayoral elections have very low turnout because they are in odd numbered years. *But, hey what about Charlie Baker in MA?* Massachusetts voters are more open to voting for the other party. How do I know? According to 538 MA has one of the highest elasticity. The elasticity of NYC districts is low, in fact some have the lowest in the nation like NY-14. The elasticity of heavily African American districts is low as well, so that could mean the black vote is inelastic. There are other reasons for that.

Comment: The table is a little confusing... please unambiguously specify **in the question text itself**, (don't rely on a URL), what ratio those percentages numbers signify.

Comment: I don't think this is anything to do with "statewide black officials". Isn't it the percentage of black voters who voted Democrat in different elections?